# Remove .php extension and solve folder name conflicts

Tags: .htaccess

So I've got these folders and files:

```
 - /user.php (file)
 - /user (folder)
     - /user/delete.php (file)
     - /user/update.php (file)
```

I'm trying to remap urls with .htaccess to be able to remove the .php extension. All the tests I made have a side effect, when I try load the */user* url, the browser redirects me to */user/* and not to the content of the */user.php*

This is configuration I'm testing:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# add .php extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Disable `MultiViews`, that is usually the culprit in that kind of scenario.

Comment: added this `Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes`
but with no success :(

Comment: You might have to set `DirectorySlash off` then. But please notice the warning in the manual, what effects this could have, https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash

Comment: Added the `DirectorySlash off`, but nothing changed

Comment: Stuff like this is hard to debug from the outside. You can enable rewrite logging, to see what exactly is going on. Or maybe change your approach, and simply use an index.php inside the user directory instead of your user.php - and use `/user/` to access it …?

Comment: Where did you set these options? And did you really restart the http server afterwards?

Comment: I'm using .htaccess file inside the root folder